# Spring Cloud Config composite config seems broken on linux

Tags: spring-cloud-config

I do have a very weird problem with the spring cloud config server.
It seems that the name for the propertySources entries is being generated differently in a windows environment than in a linux environment.

Sadly the behavior in the linux environment leads to the problem that the composite configuration is completely unusable.
For linux the name is only generated by the url of the git repo. As I am using the same repo but a different branch in the composite config the two propertySources will have the same name.
This leads to the client not merging the configs but to just completely overwrite one with the other.

Further down I will go into detail and will appreciate any help that will point me to a possible solution of the problem.
If it helps the test was done with spring boot 2.6.7 but I also tried this setup with the latest spring boot version.

I'm using a composite config which uses 2 branches of a git repo.
That way I have a general config used in all environments and specific branches with individual config values for each environment.
The environment branch has the higher order and values for existing keys from the global branch will be overwritten.

```
spring:
  application.name: configserver
  profiles:
    active:
    - composite
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        composite:
        -
          type: git
          uri: {path-to-repo}
          default-label: envlabel
          username: user
          password: pass
          clone-on-start: true
          skip-ssl-validation: true
        -
          type: git
          uri: {path-to-repo}
          default-label: global
          username: user
          password: pass
          clone-on-start: true
          skip-ssl-validation: true

server:
  port: 8081
management:
    endpoints.web.exposure.include: '*'
    endpoint.health.show-details: always
```

To compare the behavior, the same jar artifact is used in both tests!

This setup works as expected and quite nicely when running the server jar on my local windows machine.
As you can see the server includes the local temp folder in the name. That way the client can differentiate between the two propertySources and can merge them properly

Logs:

```
Adding property source: Config resource 'file [C:\Users\{User}\AppData\Local\Temp\config-repo-11072344037347215310\application-name.properties]' via location 'file:/C:/Users/{User}/AppData/Local/Temp/config-repo-11072344037347215310/'
Adding property source: Config resource 'file [C:\Users\{User}\AppData\Local\Temp\config-repo-11236171376439836700\application-name.properties]' via location 'file:/C:/Users/{User}/AppData/Local/Temp/config-repo-11236171376439836700/'
```

Postman response:

```
{
    "name": "application-name",
    "profiles": [
        "gen"
    ],
    "label": null,
    "version": null,
    "state": null,
    "propertySources": [
        {
            "name": "https://{path-to-repo}/file:C:\\Users\\{User}\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\config-repo-11072344037347215310\\application-name.properties",
            "source": {
                "env.property.01": "80000",
                "general.property.01": "41000"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "https://{path-to-repo}/file:C:\\Users\\{User}\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\config-repo-11236171376439836700\\application-name.properties",
            "source": {
                "general.property.01": "30000",
                "general.property.02": "2313",
                "general.property.03": "4321"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

However the problem arises when running the server in a linux environment. Sadly this is needed as the server should run in a docker container.
As you can see the names of the two propertySources are exactly the same. This will lead to the client only having the upper config available.
That way the entries general.property.02 and general.property.03 are lost.

Logs:

```
Adding property source: Config resource 'file [/tmp/config-repo-3444912337362291226/application-name.properties]' via location 'file:/tmp/config-repo-3444912337362291226/'
Adding property source: Config resource 'file [/tmp/config-repo-18416234976419850331/application-name.properties]' via location 'file:/tmp/config-repo-18416234976419850331/'
```

Postman response:

```
{
    "name": "application-name",
    "profiles": [
        "gen"
    ],
    "label": null,
    "version": null,
    "state": null,
    "propertySources": [
        {
            "name": "https://{path-to-repo}/application-name.properties",
            "source": {
                "env.property.01": "80000",
                "general.property.01": "41000"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "https://{path-to-repo}/application-name.properties",
            "source": {
                "general.property.01": "30000",
                "general.property.02": "2313",
                "general.property.03": "4321"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

In the log entries it is visible that those two branches are stored in different temp folders locally. The path is just not attached to the name. (Which would solve the problem)

Yet a again I would very happy about any hints on that matter.